# awk: filtering multiple files in a loop and only print a file if the number of records in that file exceeds a certian value

Tags: loops, awk, rows

I have 100-200 text files that I would like to filter rows based upon conditions being met in 2 columns.  In addition to this I only want to print the resulting files if there are more than 20 rows of data in the file.

My script for the first part is:

```
    for ID in {001..178}
    do
    cat FLD0${ID}.txt | awk '{ if($2 == "chr15" && $5>9) { print; } }' > FLD0${ID}.new.txt
    done;
```

This works fine but then I have some empty files as neither of those conditions are met and some files with only 1 or 2 lines which I suspect have low quality data anyway.  Now after the above I want only the files with 20 lines of data or more:

```
    for ID in {001..178}
    do
    cat FLD0${ID}.txt | awk '{ if(FNR>19 && $2 == "chr15" && $5>9) {  print; } }' > FLD0${ID}.new.txt
    done;
```

The second script (with the FNR) right above seems ineffectual, I still get empty files.

How can I get this loop to work as the original above with the extra condition of having 20 lines of data in each file or more.

Thanks,

Comment: Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See the 2nd awk script in @EtanReisner's answer for the right approach. Also lose the UUOC in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell creates the output file as soon as it runs the command (the `>` redirection creates the file **immediately**). You will always get empty files this way. If you don't want that then have `awk` write directly to the file so it only gets created when necessary.

```
for ID in {001..178}
do
    awk -v outfile=FLD0${ID}.new.txt 'FNR>19 && $2 == "chr15" && $5>9 {  print > outfile }' FLD0${ID}.txt
done;
```

You could even run `awk` once on all the files instead of once-per-file if you wanted to.

```
awk 'FNR>19 && $2 == "chr15" && $5>9 {  print > (FILENAME".new") }' FLD{001..178}.txt
```

(Slightly different output file name format for that one but that's just because I was being lazy. You could fix that with `split()`/etc.)

Comment: It would be better to use `FLD{001..178}.txt` as you are currently missing everything after 100 on the second part but that is the best way to do it.

Comment: @JID Indeed. I meant to just use `FLD*.txt` there but didn't delete enough but you are correct that using the original brace expansion is better.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got very sidetracked the first solution from Etan worked as I wished.  I had to look up what "UUOC" meant.  I had no idea that the loop would work without "cat" until now.  I apologize for my late reply.